# How to maximize summoner XP gain in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

What is the most *efficient* way to gain experience in LoL?
How is experience gain calculated? I've heard Dominion is better for experience than classic; is that true?

Comment: Buy an XP boost :P

Comment: Good point, though that wouldn't be very efficient for my wallet!

Comment: You have a daily XP bonus for first win. Dominion games could be more efficient because they are generally shorter than normal games. I have no source, though.

Comment: Dominion games definitely are a lot shorter than regular games. Some games in dominion last all of 10 minutes of less, while summoner's rift games last a minimum of 20 minutes(if the opposing team surrenders). I don't think I have ever seen a game last less than 20 minutes(excluding bot games).

Comment: @Zsub you get less xp from Dominion than Classic because they last less.

Comment: @Zsub is the First-of-the-Day XP as well as IP?  I thought it was just +150 IP

Comment: @NickT I'm unsure, to be honest.

Comment: There is no XP boost for first win; only an IP boost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To maximize XP gain:

- Buy XP boosts.  You can stack duration and per win boosts.
- Play PvP instead of AI
- If you insist on AI, play intermediate instead of beginner
- Surrender if you can't win (to maximize games played)
- Invite friends.  Referrals give bonus IP, which help you win (and get more exp)

However, I don't recommend trying to level up quickly.  IP is much more important for buying Tier 3 runes, and your time is better spent maximizing IP gain.

[Exp calculation](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_(summoner)):

> Current (July 2011) formula for XP winning a Normal game at level
>   15-19 is roughly `3m+25`, where `m` is the number of minutes the game
>   lasts, capped at 198. Intermediate Bot games at level 10-14 use the
>   same formula. At level 15-19, Intermediate Bot games subtract a 25%
>   penalty from that formula, and give XP for only the first 180 minutes
>   a day of play.

Comment: Actually, I think it's more efficient Dominion. You get around 110 IP for 50 minute win summoners rift. You get about 60-70 IP for 20 min Dominion. So i belive works the same for XP points (I cant test  xp with lv 30 account). You probably make more on dominion on average

Comment: Not to mention your FWOD bonus is quickly gained in dominion

Answer (score 4):

At the very beginning of the game, you are promoted fast. At lvls 19-20-21 you play all day long but it is in vain, but after being 21 lvl, again, your lvl starts to promote rapidly. Also you gain bonus XP per the first win of the day. After a first victory, you had better play dominion but if you want, because dominion might cause some unfairness due to your team's inability to re-group or lasting short time. Nevertheless you should not worry about gaining XP because, in one day, you will be 30LVL and enjoy this game more!

Comment: Your second sentence is false.  Every level costs more experience than the one before it.  The biggest cost jump is that level 21 is far more expensive than level 20, so 19-20 are actually comparatively quite short.

Answer (score 1):

Dominion isn't the best way to get XP fast. If you win, an average match that lasts less than ten minutes will give you 37 XP, and an average 3v3 match that lasts less than 20 minutes will give you 87 XP.

But the most important factor in leveling fast is playing a lot, and my suggestions is to play what you like the most. That way it doesn't get boring.

Answer (score 0):

The way to maximize xp gain is to win lots of games and to always get your first win of the day bonus.

So go win!

Best of luck.

Comment: Does the First Win of the Day help XP at all?  I thought it was just +150 IP

Comment: @NickT Your correct no XP it seems from FWD. Maybe it was before but it dose not seem that you get it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

So here are the tips to see your XP grow faster:
1. Play as much as you can.
2. Win as much as you can (if you Win, you get more IP), or at least one per day (The first win of the day gives you more points).
3. XP-Boosts are a way that enables you to get more IP from a single Game. How do you get them? You have to buy them...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still interested in this, i tested it out on a smurf account.. i got 77 exp from a SR game and 70 Exp from a dom game, so all in all dom is quicker and more efficient to level up quickly

Comment: These numbers are useless if you don't tell us how long each game was.

Answer (score 0):

Never surrender! Learn to play better and how to play defensively when losing a game. By learning to play better you will win more games and get xp faster. And your team mates won't hate you as much.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can end the match much quicker in Custom AI I would get a group of friends or acquaintances and finish those quickly.  Here is a more updated guide.

https://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/20369013-Reward-IP-XP-System-Breakdown

Answer (score 0):

You will need to stack both boosts per win and per day, so you get at least 300 xp per win.
 With the first win of the day you can get even more. By playing at least 4 games per day  you will be lvl 30 in about a month.